# Excel Function(s) to extract Firstname and Lastname from email address

Tags: excel, vba

I have email addresses in the format firstname.surname@companyname.com, these are easy enough to extract the first and surname from. My issue is I have cells in the raw data list, which contain more than one email address corresponding to different managers serving the same function. These emails are split by ";". So how do I extract first and surname from? I need a function that will work equally for the basic 'firstname.surname@companyname.com' format and cells containing 'firstname.surname@companyname.com;firstname.surname@companyname.com .....'

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try using [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function)?

Comment: Use find() to get the position of "@" then left() and right() using find() to locate the ".". Other examples on here so I won't do it, but a good exercise.

Comment: @BigBen Ah that should do it! Thank you.

Comment: Note that you could use `Split` twice: first on `;` and then on `.` Or maybe three times; `;`, then `@`, then `.` Or you could use regex. Lots of ways to do this.

Comment: @BigBen just realised actually, Split is a Google sheets function?

Comment: It's a VBA function (click the link in the first comment)? If you want a formula solution, best to not include the VBA tag, and use the excel-formula tag too.

Comment: Sorry I have absolutely confused myself. I've been looking at my screen for far too long, I've finally managed to achieve what I wanted. Thanks for the direction @BigBen

Answer (score 0):

[image: .]

A2:

```
=MID(E2,1,SEARCH(".",E2,1)-1)
```

B2:

```
=MID(E2,SEARCH(".",E2,1)+1,SEARCH("@",E2,1)-SEARCH(".",E2,1)-1)
```

C2:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(";",E2,1),0)>0,MID(MID(E2,SEARCH(";",E2,1)+1,100),1,SEARCH(".",MID(E2,1,SEARCH(";",E2,1)-1),1)-1),"")
```

D2:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(";",E2,1),0)>0,MID(MID(E2,SEARCH(";",E2,1)+1,100),SEARCH(".",MID(E2,1,SEARCH(";",E2,1)-1),1)+1,SEARCH("@",MID(E2,SEARCH(";",E2,1)+1,100),1)-SEARCH(".",MID(E2,1,SEARCH(";",E2,1)-1),1)-1),"")
```

You can combine A2 and C2 by the & if you want